# Xamarin Media Plugin Crashes when second photo is taken

Tags: c#, xamarin, plugins

I am using the Plugin.Media (jamesmontemagno/MediaPlugin) plugin for Xamarin and I am having an issue with accepting a picture. When I take the second picture (the first picture works fine) and I click to accept the image the whole app crashes with no output as to the error. I have tried trapping the error but cannot find where it is occurring. I have as suggested removing the min SDK from Android manifest, but the crash still happens.

I have tried looking through the output in visual studio but it is always different. I am assuming the code works as it takes the image and gives me data back, to be clear, it only happens when trying to accept the second image.

```
private string GetTimestamp(DateTime value)
    {
        string timestamp = value.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmssfff");
        string filename = timestamp + ".jpg";
        return filename;
    }

public Command CaptureImage => new Command(TakePicture);            
    private async void TakePicture()
    {         
        await CrossMedia.Current.Initialize();           

        if (!CrossMedia.Current.IsCameraAvailable || !CrossMedia.Current.IsTakePhotoSupported)
        {
            //Some message
            return;
        }

        var file = await CrossMedia.Current.TakePhotoAsync(new Plugin.Media.Abstractions.StoreCameraMediaOptions
        {
            Directory = "FoodSnap",
            Name = GetTimestamp(DateTime.Now) //Gets a unique file name,
            PhotoSize = Plugin.Media.Abstractions.PhotoSize.Custom,
            CustomPhotoSize = 50
        });

        if (file == null)
            return;

        FilePath = file.Path;       
    }
```

I am completely stumped as to why this is happening. I am also having trouble refreshing my ViewModel when data changes in the page I am using to take the image. I can't help wondering if this has something to do with it.

Comment: Not sure about that, but have you tried adding the extension to the file name? (like +".jpg") Even if it seems to be something related to the ViewModel, there isn't very much else to check in the MediaPlugin. Having a crash log would help to understand whats wrong!

Comment: I do have a method that adds the file extension. As mentioned it will deal with the first image, but not the second image and beyond. I think it is holding onto the first image and crashing...

Comment: I tried it twice again and this is the last output respectively before crashing:

Comment: 07-12 22:35:05.395 E/mono-rt ( 4442): ed1c3000-ed1c4000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0                                  [anon:bionic TLS guard page]
07-12 22:36:07.929 E/mono-rt ( 4687): f0478000-f047c000 rw-p 00000000 00:01 12615                              /dev/ashmem/dalvik-thread local mark stack (deleted)

Comment: seems like it maybe is an issue with the emulator as I just validated it is working on my Pixel.

Comment: Thanks, James for checking. I am seeing the issue when I deploy to play console, so It must be somewhere else in my code. It is being used in a pop-up page, so I will test outside of that.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by testing each line of code. Once I removed `PhotoSize = Plugin.Media.Abstractions.PhotoSize.Custom` I could take as many pictures as I need. I did use the Github information for the plugin.

I would be interested to know what I did wrong to cause the error. I would suggest that I have misunderstood the tutorial on Github.